# C# - Compare 2 XML strings with slightly different timestamps in each

Tags: c#, xml

If I have 2 XML strings, how can I determine whether they are the same except that timestamps in each string may be slightly different? In other words, I want to ignore the date/time values in each XML when doing the comparison.

Here is an example (showing the relevant parts of each XML):

XML 1:

```
<actionSetID>2017_01_03_20_03_52_04_0001</actionSetID><lastModifiedDateTime dt=""dateTime"">2017-01-03T20:01</lastModifiedDateTime>
```

XML 2:

```
<actionSetID>2017_01_03_20_01_07_04_0001</actionSetID><lastModifiedDateTime dt=""dateTime"">2017-01-03T20:03</lastModifiedDateTime>
```

Comment: Can you post examples of the strings?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: My preference would be to "serialize" the XML to C# objects, and then compare the resulting objects' properties. This makes sure you can handle the XML even if the order of elements/attributes is not identical.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the XML is actually a very large string that contains the elements above in it. So is there some way to exclude certain elements in each XML when comparing?

Comment: put [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) on your XML 'class' and implement CompareTo -- or just override the `Equals` form `object`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to ignore a block when a child contains certain time values. Without seeing the entire block a good answer cannot be giving.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to parse the XML strings into XDocuments and use Linq to remove unwanted nodes then compare the resulting strings. One limitation would be that the elements have to be in the same order. If you are trying to compare xml strings from the same source though this may be a reasonable expectation.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        var xDoc1 =  XDocument.Parse(xmlString1);
        Console.WriteLine(xDoc.ToString().Equals(xDoc1.ToString()));
        xDoc.Elements().Elements("lastModifiedDateTime").Remove();
        xDoc1.Elements().Elements("lastModifiedDateTime").Remove();
        Console.WriteLine(xDoc.ToString().Equals(xDoc1.ToString()));
    }
    private static string xmlString = @"<action><actionSetID>2017_01_03_20_03_52_04_0001</actionSetID><lastModifiedDateTime dt=""dateTime"">2017-01-03T20:01</lastModifiedDateTime></action>";
    private static string xmlString1 = @"<action><actionSetID>2017_01_03_20_03_52_04_0001</actionSetID><lastModifiedDateTime dt=""dateTime"">2017-01-03T20:03</lastModifiedDateTime></action>";
```

Output

```
False
True
```